# WiX - Create MSI using msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, wix, votive

Hi I have a Wix (Votive) Visual Studio project which creates an MSI from my WiX file.

I want to integrate this into our continuous integration by putting into an msbuild script.

Reading the project source file did not help and could not find any clear info from google.

How do I create an MSI using a WiX (wsx) script from an MSBuild script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx) very useful.

[Automate Releases With MSBuild And Windows Installer XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163456.aspx)

and [Using the WiX Toolset to Integrate Setup into Your Development Process](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/aa302186.aspx)

Comment: 3rd link is dead now.

Comment: Recommend following link as replacement [WiX Toolset - Working with MSBuild](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/)

Comment: @AKeefe - why didn't you edit the answer to replace the link?